# Permission Denied when running Python and Pip through Shellscript

Tags: python-3.x, shell, pip, windows-10

I'm trying to create a setup script for a python project. Assume that python 3.8 and pip are already installed properly and that running them directly works, but when running them through an sh file breaks with a permission denied. Python is installed globally.

OS: Windwos10
Py: 3.8

Below are the sh scripts that break

```sh
ROOT_PATH='./'
if [ ! -f "$ROOT_PATH.env" ]; then
  echo 'Copying .env file from template'
  cp "$ROOT_PATH.env.template" "$ROOT_PATH.env"
fi

echo 'Installing app dependencies...'
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user

echo 'Run migrations'
python -m flask db upgrade
```